# Bootstrap 1 row on LG screens and 2 rows on MD screens

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In Bootstrap, I would like to have 1 row with 12 cells on a large screen and for a smaller screen I would like to have 2 rows with 6 cells.

A schema to understand well:

[image]

I tried this:

```
<div class="col-xs-1 "><br/></div> 
<div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2">
    <h1>1</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2 ">
    <h1>2</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2 ">
    <h1>3</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2 ">
    <h1>4</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2 ">
    <h1>5</h1>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-1 hidden-lg "><br/></div> 
<div class="col-xs-1 hidden-lg "><br/></div> 

<div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2 ">
    <h1>6</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2">
    <h1>7</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2 ">
    <h1>8</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2 ">
    <h1>9</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-xs-2 ">
    <h1>10</h1>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 "><br/></div>
```

But what I've got, is this:

[image]

I don't know why, but these 2 cells are stacked:

```
<div class="col-xs-1 hidden-lg "><br/></div> 
<div class="col-xs-1 hidden-lg "><br/></div>
```

And I don't understand why.

Look at this Fiddle: [Fiddle OK](http://jsfiddle.net/x3rowL4g/1)

When I have 0 on some cells, that works, but if I want to remove 0 to just have empty cells, that fails: [Fiddle FAIL](http://jsfiddle.net/x3rowL4g/2/)

Comment: What about a div with `.col-lg-offset-1` at the start of your `<div>`s?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row>div {border:1px solid #000;height:20px;}
@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) {
.row>div:nth-child(6) {clear:left} /* to put the 6th block in new row */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2">1</div>
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2">2</div>
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2">3</div>
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2">4</div>
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2">5</div>
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2">6</div>
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2">7</div>
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2">8</div>
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2">9</div>
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-2">10</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know either I got your question correct or not, but If its what i am trying to explain, then you just need to add this single line.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `col-lg-1 col-md-2`.

Demo can be found at [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3rowL4g/). (make sure to resize the *result* window)

Comment: It's not what I ask. I have just 10 cells with content (not 12 as your example) and some empty cells . And these empty cells make this issue.

Comment: Look with your Fiddle with my example : http://jsfiddle.net/x3rowL4g/1/ 
I would this, but if you remove the 0 and you let cells empty, that's fail.

Comment: @dramixx my apologies! Do these need to be explicitly empty cells (as in a `div`, or is a gap of one cell width sufficient (a solution with `col-lg-offset-1`)?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION :** OK I solved it in adding `style="clear:both;"` to my second empty cell

See here : http://jsfiddle.net/x3rowL4g/3/